# jQuery tablesorter widget-filter-formatter-select2 with a predefined filter list?

Tags: jquery, filter, widget, tablesorter

Successfully, I implemented the tablesorter filter widget, to select multiple options at the same time with partial matching without any problems (this plugin is great!):

https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-select2.html

However, my table is more complex.

| Person | Language |
| --- | --- |
| A | ENG, DEU, FRZ, SPA |
| B | ENG, SLO, RUS |
| C | DEU, FRZ |

Desired content of the filter dropdown: ENG / DEU / FRZ etc.
(not each combination once)

**Is it possible to give a predefined list instead of using the unique values selected from the all cells of this col?**
I went throught the JS code, but could not figure out how do integrate an additional arguments containting such a list.

Answer (score 0):

After relooking at the documentation I found what I needed:

```
// option added in v2.16.0
  filter_selectSource : {
    // Alphanumeric match (prefix only)
    // added as select2 options (you could also use select2 data option)
    2 : function(table, column) {
      return ['ENG', 'DEU', 'FRZ', 'SLO', 'RUS'];
    }
  }
```

This works fine, but does not include child rows. **How can I also filter child rows?**

Comment: Implemented workaround: Instead of using childrows I added div-environments. So, parts of my table can be collapsed but will still be filtered by this cool select2-filter.